# Unexpected netstat output in DNAT conditions

Tags: iptables, tcp, proxy, netstat, socks

So, here I have a basic setup with SOCKS5 proxy listening on, oh, say 8123

I redirect TCP to the proxy via `iptables`

From `iptables` perspective everything looks peachy, 
`iptables -t nat -v -L` shows

```
DNAT tcp -- any any anywhere anywhere to:127.0.01:8123
```

From the "practical" perspective it's working (Google's account activity, geoip websites and http://ipleak.net/ specifically are showing proxy's external  IP)

So it would seem the proxy is working as intended.

However, if I try to do a `netstat`, I see things like

```
tcp 0 0 10.201.87.64:59949 74.125.141.104:443 ESTABLISHED [browser's PID]
```

`74.125.141.104:443` is google.

What I would have **expected** `netstat` to show is the proxy's listening IP (localhost) instead of the remote server's (google's) IP.

Is the browser "leaking" past the `iptable` rule for some reason (and if so, why do google's account details show a connection from the proxy's external IP) ?

Or is it `netstat` being weird and oblivious to the fact that DNAT is taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your browser is concerned, it's connected to 74.125.141.104. A DNAT doesn't change that fact. If you DNAT port 80 coming from the internet to port 80 on an internal webserver at e.g. 10.201.87.80, would you expect netstat on the remote system to show 10.201.87.80 as the remote IP or your external IP?

PS: 10.201.87.64:599449 is impossible, port numbers are 65535 or less (16 bits).

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining, that makes sense. - and port number is a typo, of course